# Enable and disable Control on database value change

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a situation where I have to disable certain controls on database value change.

For that I have used following code.

Here I am disabling the controls in the panel on 0 value and on any other values I am enabling it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test_control : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string test1;
    List<double> _data = new List<double>();
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {       
        int maxId;
        using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        using (SqlCommand dataCommand =
                new SqlCommand("select top 1 RunMode from MCASMonitoring_Rev1 order by Id desc", dataConnection))
        {    
            dataConnection.Open();
            maxId = Convert.ToInt32(dataCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            TextBox1.Text = maxId.ToString();
            if (TextBox1.value == 0)
            {
                Panel1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Panel1.Enabled = true;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

But the situation is that I have to refresh the page to achieve this operation. But What I want is that I need it in runtime without refreshing the entire page.

Comment: use Asynchronous Postbacks

Comment: Use a timer, and poll db by sending async postbacks in intervals. Refer [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1871210.aspx?Reflect+the+changes+in+page+without+page+refresh). Hope it helps

Comment: you can use page method also in your application.

Comment: @Manish Can you please provide me with the example.

Answer (score 0):

SnPandya....

Suggestion 1

Panels should be disable based on DB values...So definitely once you have to come across server side.
Now, once you have DB values then you can call javascript from serverside and disable any controls you want........

Suggestion 2

Put your controls inside "Updatepanel" then you will not feel any page postback